# Installing drivers consecutively for all interfaces/ports within an inf file

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader, xiaomi, usb-drivers

This concerns an inf file which contain a number of interfaces/ports that need support of drivers. Instead of installing the driver for each interface/port one by one, is there a way to install the driver consecutively (one after another) to all the ports/interfaces in one go?

Does installing the driver for interface/port at the bottom of the pack ensure driver is installed for all interfaces/ports.
Hoping someone in the forum can give an answer

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the driver does not contain the USB device IDs of your device you have to manually select the correct one. You did not include any information on your device and it's state (bootloader, recovery or regular boot) so it is not possible to tell you which driver to select.

Comment: @Robert:The first image shows the interfaces for adb & fastboot mode that require Google Usb drivers (androidwinusb.inf) & the second image is of Mediatek USB Vcom driver & the ports that require drivers .                    Just want to know for this type of INF file,does selecting the bottom option auto install drivers for all interfaces/ports

Comment: This is the dialog for manually updating and selecting an appropriate driver.